# Azure deployment failing due to NetFx451

Tags: azure, deployment

While deploying your project to azure you receive the error

```
Azure Deployment: The feature named NetFx451 that is required by the uploaded package is not available in the OS * chosen for the deployment.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix this error update your *.cscfg files in your azure project.  In each file you will find `osFamily="3"` (can be something else) change this to `osFamily="4"`.

Publish your project again and it should now deploy

Answer (score 8):

For .Net 4.6.1 You need to select osFamily="5" inside your *.cscfg files and run [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/31/not-able-to-upload-role-after-upgrading-the-sdk.aspx) blog post also explains how to do that and why the change in the ".cscfg" file working in more details.

It will work only if you have chosen "Windows Server 2012 R2" (OS 4.x) as a guest OS first, because it will have the target framework runtime installed. Only modifying the config file can cause problems.

It seems there is one and the same message if both the OS or .NET versions are wrong.

I had an "Windows 2008 R2" (OS 2.6), and it said this error message about the NetFx version.
Changing the OS to "Windows Server 2012 R2" (OS 4.x) fixed the .NET version problem, but i still got the same error. Modifying the config file fixes the issue.